# What is the intuition behind Liouville's theorem in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking for an intuitive motivation for Liouville's theorem from complex analysis. 
If somebody could illustrate this with a simple example, that would be great. Thank you so much.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116896/liouvilles-theorem-with-your-bare-hands and https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323342

Comment: this is a subtle property as there are entire non-constant functions that are bounded on any ray through the origin, so the materials linke din the mathoverflow answer are usueful

Comment: For more detailed answers, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731959/intuition-behind-liouvilles-theorem)

Answer (score 4):

My point of view may be wrong. An extremely important fact about analytics functions is the mean formula : the value of f at $z$ is its mean on every circle centered around $z$. So, for an entire function f, the radii of theses circles can be chosen arbitrary large. Thus, if f is bounded, the value of f at every point $z$, will be its means "at the infinity". Consequently f is constant.

Answer (score 3):

Much like polynomials on the real line, (non-constant) complex analytic functions blow up.  After all, an analytic function is sort of an infinite version of a polynomial.

Comment: what about $\sin x$ on the real line

Comment: This is flawed.

Comment: @piombino $\sin x$ isn't a polynomial.

Comment: this is much subtler than that as I noted above there are entire nonconstant functions that are bounded on every line through the origin

Comment: @Conrad that the analogy is flawed is duly noted.  Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the analogy is flawed, only incomplete as for functions of finite order (so the Taylor coefficients $|a_n|$ decrease fast enough) it has some value, since then the function must be unbounded on many lines and then rotating it, one can assume it is unbounded on the reals (eg $\cos$ becomes $\cosh$)

Answer (score 0):

Liouville's theorem and few other related theorems  depict the *rigid* behaviour of an entire function. In contrast to the real-analytic functions where boundedness can be imposed solely, the complex analytic functions are sensitive to boundedness and adapt constant behaviour. This rigidity can also be seen in *Identity theorem* and *Open mapping theorem*.